# How to load all items at once in recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, countdowntimer

I am using CountDownTimer in recyclerview for every items. I am facing issue for items which are not visible on screen. Countdown starts for those items when they get visible on screen. I need solution: How to load all items at once in recyclerview in android.

Comment: Please share code that you have tried yet.It will help others to understand more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try embedding the recycler view inside a nested scroll view. This way all items will be loaded at once even though it violates the purpose of the recycler view.

Comment: Thanks, its working but scrolling is not properly working.

Comment: set nested scrolling to false on recyclerview.

Answer (score 2):

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
  />
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. But scrolling is not working properly for 1st and last item. Both items gets half visible on the screen.